# How to make a multiple api call on submission of a form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I have a Form  with 10 (may vary) rows  of data ,On Submission I need to make 10(may vary) api call one for each row. I am using axios to make  the api calls. How can I make  multiple api calls on a single click in a best and efficient way ?.

Comment: why do you want to make 10 api calls, just submit the form data on single api call

Comment: because the api takes in only one item not all at a time ,i.e it is update item and not update all. It will be better to have api which updates all  but I  am not in a liberty to change the api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axios supports the `Promise` api, so you could use `Promise.all` to handle all 10 requests at once. Here is a small example:

```js
const requests = [
  { url: "https://some.url", body: { some: "body" } },
  { url: "https://some.other.url", body: { some: "other body" } },
  // As many as you like
];

const promises = requests.map(request => axios.post(request.url, request.body));
const result = Promise.all(promises).catch(error => console.log(`Someting went wrong: ${error}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Bluebird as well.

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';

 deleteRequests = (requests) => {
       let promiseCollection = [];

        try {
            requests.map((request, index) => {
                    promiseCollection.push(axios.delete(request.API + request.ids));
            });
            return Bluebird.all(promiseCollection);
        }
        catch (error) {
        }
}
```